# How to directly get the full URL of current experience site page in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, community, lightning-experience, navigationmixin.navigate

I have a certain URL in Experience Site (Its in LWR):

https://randomwebpage.sandbox.my.site.com/connect/insights

When I use the following code

import basePath from '@salesforce/community/basePath';

I see it gives /connect. This is the community basepath URL. /connect/insights is coming when I have used lightning navigation and gone to /insights appending it after the community basepath as per the following existing code ((in another LWC component)

```
import basePath from '@salesforce/community/basePath';

 this.pageReference = {
            type: 'standard__webPage',
            attributes: {
            url: basePath + this.tabsetMap.get(evt.target.dataset.value).Target
            }
 this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](this.pageReference);
```

the thing is now I need the full URL:

https://randomwebpage.sandbox.my.site.com/connect/insights or atleast the part /connect/insights so that I can go to

https://randomwebpage.sandbox.my.site.com/connect/insights/page1
https://randomwebpage.sandbox.my.site.com/connect/insights/page2

Using lightning navigation. Im stuck and unable to come to a solution. I don't wish to hardcode connect/insights so I can perform a string concatenation and generate a url for lightning navigation. Is there an alternative? Note I cannot access this.tabsetMap.get(evt.target.dataset.value).Target   because this is in another component. now I am in connect/insights where Im displaying another experience page (diff LWC component).

Answer (score -1):

to get the full url you can use : window.location.href.

try it :

```
console.log(window.location.href)
```

Hope I helped.

Comment: This does not work, at least not in an LWR Experience site. It returns "about:blank".